# ¿Se puede pasar un int a una zona de memoria compartida en c?

Tags: c

Estoy intentando que un proceso escriba en una zona de memoria compartida, pero al pasar un int en la zona de memoria se ven caracteres extraños, si paso una cadena se ve bien la cadena.

```c
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define OBJETO_MEM "/mem_comp"
#define TAMANO_MEM 4
int main(){
        int fd;
        char *ptr;
        char buf[] = "Hola mundo";
        int *iptr;
        int ibuf[]={10};
        int num1=20;
        fd = shm_open(OBJETO_MEM, O_CREAT | O_TRUNC | O_RDWR, 00600);
        if(fd==-1){
                printf("error no se puede crear el objeto de memoria \n");
                exit(1);
        }
        if(-1==ftruncate(fd, TAMANO_MEM)){
                printf("error no se puede truncar tamaño \n");
                exit(1);

        }

        write(fd,&num1, sizeof(num1));
        //ptr = mmap(0, sizeof(ibuf), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
        //if(ptr==MAP_FAILED){
         //       printf("Error mapeando memoria \n");
        //}

        return 0;


}
```

Si en vez de `write(fd,&num1, sizeof(num1));` pongo `write(fd,"abcd", sizeof("abcd"));` me funciona.

Si miro en nano `/dev/shm/mem_comp` con el primer ejemplo lo que obtengo es: `^T^@^@^@`

Si hago un `cat /dev/shm/mem_comp` no se imprime nada, si pusiese "abcd" sí lo hace.

Comment: Si intentas guardar texto en lugar de números funciona?

Comment: holaaa, sí, con cadena no hay problema, se encuentra en la memoria compartida, pero si le paso un número me hace cosas extrañas, me imagino que el error debe ser mío, de concepto o algo así, pero me parece que debería funcionar...

Comment: Si escribes un entero... debes leer un entero. Un entero se codifica como 4 bytes **en binario**, que supongo que serán los mismos 4 bytes con valores extraños que lees en el otro lado. Los tipos numéricos no son _human friendly_, se trata de valores binarios

Comment: Esa es una respuesta que me podría haber dado mi profesor de sistemas operativos, botando, pero lo suficientemente ambigua para no entenderla de primeras. Gracias aún así. Usando la **herramienta xxd** se obtienen los valores que quieres en hexadecimal por si alguien lo necesita en el futuro. En cuanto a lo de "si escribes un entero... debes leer un entero", si recibes el entero con read lo puedes leer e imprimir sin problemas con printf.

Comment: @eferion no sé como marcarte como respuesta ni si se pueden dar puntos. Thx de nuevo.

Comment: @programador_en_Apuros en realidad, era un comentario, no una respuesta. Así que no te preocupes que no se puede votar. Me alegra haberte ayudado